# Translate function: "error:sequence is not a vector of chars"

Tags: r, dna-sequence

I'm struggling with the translate function:

I have a matrix of sequences and I can't manage to figure out why the translate function would not work.

Here is my script :

```
 head(myseq)
     [,1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[1,] "CAATTAAGATGCAGTTACTTCGCTGTTTTTCAATATTTTCTGTTATTGCTAGCGTTTTAGCAGCTGGAGAAGTCCAGTTGGTTGAATCCGGTGGCGGGTTGGTTCAACCTGGCCGTTCCCTGCGCCTTTCTTGTGCCGCTTCAGGCTTTACCTTCGACGATTATGCCATGCATTGGGTACGCCAAGCTCCGGGCAAAGGTCTGGAATGGGTGAGTGCCATTACCTGGAATAGCGGCCACATTGACTATGCGGATAGCGTCGAAGGGCGCTTTACCATTAGCCGTGATAACGCGAAGAACAGCCTCTATCTGGACATGAACAGCTTACGTGCGGAAGATACCGCAGTGTACTATTGCGCTAAGGTCAGCTATCTGAGTACTGCCAGTTCCCTGGATTATTGGGGTCAAGGAACCCTGGTGACCGTGTCAAGCGGCGGAGGCGGTTCTGGTGGTGGAGGCAGTBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
[2,] "CAATTAAGATGCAGTTACTTCGCTGTTTTTCAATATTTTCTGTTATTGCTAGCGTTTTAGCAGCTGGAGAAGTCCAGTTGGTTGAATCCGGTGGCGGGTTGGTTCAACCTGGCCGTTCCCTGCGCCTTTCTTGTGCCGCTTCAGGCTTTACCTTCGACGATTATGCCATGCATTGGGTACGCCAAGCTCCGGGCAAAGGTCTGGAATGGGTGTCTGCGGCTAGTTGGAGTGGTGGCCACATCGATTATGCCGATAGCGTCGAAGGGCGCTTTACCATTAGCCGTGATAACGCGAAGAACAGCCTCTATCTGGACATGAACAGCTTACGTGCGGAAGATACCGCAGTGTACTATTGCGCTAAGGTCAGCTATCTGAGTACTGCCAGTTCCCTGGATTATTGGGGTCAAGGAACCCTGGTGACCGTGTCAAGCGGCGGAGGCGGTTCTGGTGGTGGAGGCAGTBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"

translate(myseq[1,],frame=2,sens=F)

Error in s2n(seq, levels = s2c("tcag")) :sequence is not a vector of chars
```

I checked my parameters :

```
class(myseq[1,])

[1] "character"

is.vector(myseq[1,])

[1] TRUE
```

So I assume that I missed something but I can't figure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

If you are using [`seqinr::translate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/3.4-5/topics/translate) then you can try wrapping your DNA string with [`s2c`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/3.4-5/topics/s2c).

```
myString <- "AAACCCGGGTTT"
library(seqinr)

# Without s2c
translate(myString)
Error in s2n(seq, levels = s2c("tcag")) : 
  sequence is not a vector of chars

# With s2c
translate(s2c(myString))
[1] "K" "P" "G" "F"
```

**Explanation:**

Vector of characters that `translate()` requires is `"A" "A" "A" "C" "C" "C" "G" "G" "G" "T" "T" "T"` and not `"AAACCCGGGTTT"`.
You can generate vector like this using `strsplit()`:

```
strsplit(myString, "")
[[1]]
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "C" "C" "C" "G" "G" "G" "T" "T" "T"

all(strsplit(myString, "")[[1]] == s2c(myString))
[1] TRUE
```